Having trouble uploading an image to a website using Selenium
I've created a script using Python and Selenium to upload an image from a local folder to this webpage. The website requires a Google login to access the page with the upload option.
Once the login is complete, the site automatically redirects me to the target page. After the browser reaches the target page, it is necessary to click on Full Remake. Now, the script tries to use the button Drag & Drop your image or Browse to upload an image, but it selects the Browse button and does nothing. This is the image I'm trying to upload on that site.
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

url = 'https://reroom.ai/'

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=options)

gmail = ""     #gamil address here
password = ""  #password here

driver.get(url)
original_window = driver.current_window_handle
driver.maximize_window()
try:
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@type='button'][contains(.,'Accept')]"))).click()
except Exception as err:
    pass
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[./img[@alt='google']][contains(.,'Sign in with Google')]"))).click()
time.sleep(5)
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.new_window_is_opened)
driver.switch_to.window([window for window in driver.window_handles if window != original_window][0])
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input#identifierId"))).send_keys(gmail)
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#identifierNext"))).click()
time.sleep(5)
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[name='Passwd']"))).send_keys(password)
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button/span[.='Next']"))).click()
driver.switch_to.window(original_window)
time.sleep(5)
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[.='Full Remake']"))).click()
image_path = r'C:\Users\C.L\Desktop\Jonathan\c7OgQ1Qh.jpeg'
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "img[class='object-contain']")))
time.sleep(5)
file_input = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[@class='filepond--label-action'][.='Browse']")))
time.sleep(5)
file_input.send_keys(image_path)

How can I upload the image on that website?

Have you try to use the API ? Also, you should use the Selenium implicit waits, it's better for always wait a same amount of time.

You should have looked for the input element to send image. The object which actually takes in the image in your application is :- file_input =driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@class='filepond--browser']") and not the browse link.
Following code should work Now :-
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

url = 'https://reroom.ai/'

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=options)

gmail = ""     #gamil address here
password = ""  #password here

driver.get(url)
original_window = driver.current_window_handle
driver.maximize_window()
try:
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@type='button'][contains(.,'Accept')]"))).click()
except Exception as err:
    pass
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[./img[@alt='google']][contains(.,'Sign in with Google')]"))).click()
time.sleep(5)
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.new_window_is_opened)
driver.switch_to.window([window for window in driver.window_handles if window != original_window][0])
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input#identifierId"))).send_keys(gmail)
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#identifierNext"))).click()
time.sleep(5)
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[name='Passwd']"))).send_keys(password)
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button/span[.='Next']"))).click()
driver.switch_to.window(original_window)
time.sleep(15)
WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[.='Full Remake']"))).click()
image_path = r'C:\Users\C.L\Desktop\Jonathan\c7OgQ1Qh.jpeg'
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[@class='filepond--label-action'][.='Browse']")))
time.sleep(5)
file_input =driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@class='filepond--browser']")
time.sleep(5)
file_input.send_keys(image_path)
time.sleep(5)

